# Using smart pointers to manage buffers

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I recently started to migrate many of my existing classes over to using smart pointers and I have a few questions about how to port some code that I think could benefit from the use of smart pointers (but I might be wrong of course).  I have a **UtlMemBuffer** buffer manager class shown below via its header file.

Essentially, this class owns a vector of buffers made up of void*/length pairs. The buffer management is implemented via a helper method (**UtlMemBuffer::append** - the implementation of which is also shown below).

I would like to make this class use the new **C++11** smart pointers so that ownership could be well defined and reallocation minimized.  To use this class, client code typically passes in its own raw pointer buffer/length to the constructor, or it can call append.  Eventually when the **UtlMemBuffer**'s destructor is called, it frees its own copy, ensuring that there are no memory leaks while the caller is responsible for its copy.  I think that instead of passing in raw pointers, using a **std::shared_ptr** would obviate the need for this type of double buffer ownership (i.e. the caller would be responsible for newing up a **std::shared_ptr** and passing it to the **UtlMembuffer**.

The biggest challenge as I see it is supporting the read method (the interface is similar to the way a file works) where I need to pass back flattened memory via a raw pointer.  Perhaps a better design approach would be for me to pass back a std::unique_ptr which I create from flattening the internal collection of shared_ptrs.  I am not quite sure what the best approach would be althought I would have to change quite a bit of current code that uses the class to take that approach.

Should the callers all pass in **std::shared_ptr** pointers for ex.  I wonder what the best approach to making this conversion would be.

I am pretty new at this smart pointer business so any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

```
/**
 * Smart Buffer class
 */
class UtlMemBuffer
{
public:
    // default constructor
    UtlMemBuffer(
        const UtlPath& rBufferPath = UtlPath::ssNull,
        const void* pBytes = NULL,
        const size_t& rBufLength = 0);

    // copy constructor
    UtlMemBuffer(const UtlMemBuffer& rhs);

    // move constructor
    UtlMemBuffer(UtlMemBuffer&& rhs);

    inline void swap(UtlMemBuffer& rhs) throw() {
        // enable ADL (not necessary in our case, but good practice)
        using std::swap;
        // no need to swap base members - as we are topmost class
        swap(mBufferPath, rhs.mBufferPath);
        swap(mBufferLength, rhs.mBufferLength);
        swap(mBufferBlocks, rhs.mBufferBlocks);
    }

    // unified assignment operator
    UtlMemBuffer& operator=(UtlMemBuffer rhs);

    // destructor - pure virtual
    virtual ~UtlMemBuffer();

    // add buffer to this one
    virtual OsStatus append(
        const void* pBytes,
        const size_t& rBufLength,
        size_t& rBufLengthWritten);

    // comparator
    bool operator==(const UtlMemBuffer& rhs) const;

    // comparator
    bool operator<(const UtlMemBuffer& rhs) const;

    // determine the size of the buffer
    size_t size() const;

    /**
     * comparable interface
     *
     * @returns 0 if equal, negative val if less than &
     *          negative value if greater.
     */
    virtual int compareTo(const UtlMemBuffer& rhs) const;

    /** copy the bytes into the designated buffer */
    OsStatus read (void* pReturnBuffer,
        const size_t& rMemBufferOffset,
        const size_t& rReturnBufferLength,
        size_t& rBytesRead) const;

    // free existing linked list of blocks
    void clear();

    // path property
    void setBufferPath(const UtlPath& rBufferPath);

    UtlPath getBufferPath() const;

private:
    typedef std::vector< std::pair<void*, size_t> > MemBufInfo;

    // the name of the buffer (sort of file name)
    UtlPath mBufferPath;

    // this is updated whenever we append data
    size_t mBufferLength;

    // here we have a collection of received appends (effectively blocks)
    MemBufInfo mBufferBlocks;
};
```

Here is the helper method which manages access to the vector of buffer blocks.  As you can see, it reallocates the raw pointers and stores them in the **mBufferBlocks** member.

```
OsStatus
UtlMemBuffer::append(const void* pBytes,
    const size_t& rBufLength,
    size_t& rBytesWritten)
{
    rBytesWritten = 0;
    if (pBytes != NULL) {
        void* block = new char [rBufLength];
        memcpy(block, pBytes, rBufLength);
        mBufferBlocks.push_back(std::make_pair(block, rBufLength));
        rBytesWritten = rBufLength;
        mBufferLength += rBufLength;
    }
    return OS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the author had simply used char* to represent memory bytes, like is usual, then you could have simply stored vectors instead of pairs of void*/len.

That's what I'd probably do here.  Assuming you don't have to do any actual destruction of objects in this memory space, just cast to char* and stick in a vector.

Comment: Well I still need to know the length of each buffer so changing from a void* to a char* really would not make that much difference.  The void*/len or char*/len are necessary in order to keep an eye on the length of each buffer.  Unfortunately arrays or char[] arrays - unlike their java counterparts do not have length information.

Comment: @johnco3 : No one is suggesting changing from `void*` to `char*`, the suggestion is to change from `void*` to `std::vector<char>`, which _does_ know its own length.

Comment: Perhaps it was not clear from the Header File, but the intent behind the std::vector< std::pair<void*, size_t> > was simply to be a list of appended individual buffers that are simply "pushed_back" in the append code.  Each buffer in that vector has a pointer and a length field.  Think of it as a sort of linked list of individual separate buffers.  The only time I would need to flatten these into a vector<char> for example would be if a user called the read method.  I hope it is clear why I need a separate length field - it has absolutely nothing to do with void vs char.

Comment: In my case, I used `std::vector<char> buffer`, and to give the underlying buffer to the C library I was using, I used `&buffer[0]`.